# General FizzBuzz in Scala

Tags: functional-programming, scala, collections, fizzbuzz

I wanted to create a FizzBuzz implementation that both showcases the strengths of Scala (Functional paradigm and collections) and is general enough to anticipate the typical interview follow-up questions. i.e. What if fizz was for factors of 4 instead? What if we wanted to replace factors of 7 with "foo"?

```
object FizzBuzz extends App {

  def fizzbuzz(factors: Map[Int, String])(currentNumber: Int): String = {
    val words = factors.filter(currentNumber % _._1 == 0).values
    if (words.isEmpty) currentNumber.toString else words.mkString("")
  }

  private final val Factors = Map(3 -> "fizz", 5 -> "buzz")
  private final val Range = 1 to 100

  Range.map(fizzbuzz(Factors)).foreach(println)
}
```

I would appreciate any feedback on how I can make my Scala more idiomatic.

Comment: Don't edit your code after it's been reviewed.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I have created a Meta discussion about clarifying in the tour here: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/add-question-editing-recommendations-to-community-tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) is not guaranteed to impose or preserve any order for its entries.  For example, if I change `Factors` to …

```
private final val Factors = Map(3 -> "a", 5 -> "b", 6 -> "c", 7 -> "d", 8 -> "e", 9 -> "f")
```

… I get:

> ```
> ⁞
> 89
> bcfa
> d
> 92
> a
> 94
> b
> cae
> 97
> d
> fa
> b
> ```

So, the fact that you get "fizzbuzz" rather than "buzzfizz" is based on luck, not skill.  If you want to guarantee "fizzbuzz", you need a [`scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to be able to change the mapping of fizz and buzz I would think to make a funcion that take a function as an argument that maps a number to a string:

```
def fizzbuzz(countUntil: Int)(mapping: Int => String) = {
  for (i <- 0 to countUntil) yield mapping(i)
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
// Map Int to String using pattern matching with a guard
fizzbuzz(30) {
  case fizzbuzz if fizzbuzz % 3 == 0 && fizzbuzz % 5 == 0 => "fizzbuzz"
  case fizz if fizz % 3 == 0 => "fizz"
  case buzz if buzz % 5 == 0 => "buzz"
  case f => s"$f"
}.foreach(println)
```

The pattern matching code could be an `if/else` just as long as it takes an `Int` and returns a `String` for example:

```
// Map Int to String using if/else
fizzbuzz(30){ f =>
  if (f % 3 == 0 && f % 5 == 0) "fizzbuzz"
  else if (f % 3 == 0) "fizz"
  else if (f % 5 == 0) "buzz"
  else s"$f"
}.foreach(println)
```

Comment: That's a terrible use of pattern matching.

Comment: @Nico What makes it so terrible?

Comment: you're just wrapping an `if then else` into a pattern matching for no added benefit

Comment: @Nico If you're going for performance or if you perfer the syntax then go for an `if/else` however I pefer the pattern matching in this case.
But for a complete example I've added an `if/else` version to my answer.

Comment: I'll stop answering after this because I suspect it will turn into a lengthy discussion with no real outcome. Your pattern matching isn't doing anything. It's just wasted disk space, compiler time, and human time reading it.

Comment: He's saying that your pattern matching doesn't actually match any patterns -- `case _` means the same as `default` in other languages. In this case, I'm not sure pattern-matching can be used (I don't know Scala very well), and you should probably prefer `if`/`else` (your second version).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I see your point when you put it that way but the `_` can be a name instead.
Pattern matching can be used; I've run both examples I've given and they both work.

Comment: @Soapy They both work, yes, but that doesn't mean that one doesn't pointlessly use `match`. There is absolutely no reason to use `match` in your first call example; your second is simpler, quite possibly faster, and easier to read.

Comment: @Soapy The main drawback I see with your approach is that the number of cases grows drastically when there are more possible factors. For example, if I wanted factors of 3 -> "fizz", 4 -> "buzz", 5 -> "foo", 6 -> "bar", you would need an if case for each combination of those options. (case 3, case 3&4, case 3&5, case 3&4&5 ...) which would be difficult to maintain. Although I appreciate the suggestion!